# Nest.js sending custom response to client from an Exception

Tags: javascript, express, axios, nuxt.js, nestjs

I'm facing a problem that i'd like to fix...

I'm working on a procject using Nest.js as Backend framework for APIs, and Nuxt.js for Client...
Everything is working fine, but when i'm trying to throw an error in a service, that is injected into the controller, i'm not able to send a custom response to the client. Those the scenarios that i've faced:

**account.service.ts**

```
 async createAccount(_account: AccountEntity){
    return await this.accountRepository.save(_account)
}

async _accountExists(_account: AccountEntity) {
    const itExists = await this.findOne(_account)
    if(itExists){
        throw new ConflictException(`Username already exists!`)
    }
}
```

account.controller.ts

```
@Post()
@UseFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter())
async createAccount(@Body() userAccount: createAccountDto, @Res() res: Response) {
    try {
        await this.accountService._accountExists(userAccount).then(async () => {
            return await this.accountService.createAccount(userAccount)
        })
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(e.status).json(e.message)
    }
}
```

This returns me this error in the client, if the user already exists but it doesn't send the json to the client.

```
POST http://localhost:3000/account 409 (Conflict)
Request failed with status code 409
```

If i change it res.json(e), it sends me to the client the error with status 201 as you can see in the image, but the response is fine in all scenarios. 
[image]
So the question is... how i can get this response with correct status code?

This is the Exception Filter:

```
 import { ExceptionFilter, Catch, ArgumentsHost, HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { Request, Response } from 'express';

    @Catch(HttpException)
    export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
        catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
            const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
            const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
            const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
            const status = exception.getStatus();

            response
                .status(status)
                .json({
                    statusCode: status,
                    name: exception.name,
                    message: exception.message.message,
                    timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
                    path: request.url,
                });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the problem itself wasn't the server, but from client.
Loggin the **errors** doesnt log the object, you need to log **errors.response**